# Column pair subtraction - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate for a given column pair the difference for each `customer_id` in a more dynamic way. Column pairs are always in the same order i.e. `customer_id` will always be `column_1` and `column_3` will always be subtracted by `column_2` and `column_5 - column_4` and so on...

Sample df

```
customer_id   count_sessions_q4_2021  count_sessions_q1_2022  purchases_q4_2021  purchases_q1_2022 
203           100                     110                     12                 11
484           210                     215                     21                 18
582           409                     400                     35                 32
```

Expected output_df

```
customer_id   count_sessions_diff   purchases_diff
203           10                    -1
484           5                     -3 
582          -9                     -3
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
df.replace('null', np.nan, inplace=True)
df_2 = df.set_index('customer_id').apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

a = np.arange(len(df_2.columns)) // 2

s = (df_2.columns
           .to_series()
           .str.extract('^(.*?)\d', expand=False)
           .groupby(a)
           .agg('_'.join)
           .add('_diff'))

df_2 = df_2.groupby(a, axis=1).diff(1).dropna(how='all', axis=1)

df_2.columns = s
```

but I am getting the following error:
`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MultiIndex comes in handy here, as it allows for a relatively easy way to reshape and manipulate the dataframe:

Set the customer id as index, and reshape the remaining columns into a multi index

```py
temp = df.set_index('customer_id')
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split(r'_(q\d+)_', expand = True)

temp
            count_sessions      purchases
                        q4   q1        q4   q1
                      2021 2022      2021 2022
customer_id
203                    100  110        12   11
484                    210  215        21   18
582                    409  400        35   32
```

Iterate through the first level of the columns in a list comprehension and compute the differences; in this case we can tell that 2022 trails 2021 for each section, so we'll multiply our outcome by -1 to flip it:

```py
keys = temp.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
outcome = [temp[key].agg(np.subtract.reduce, axis = 1).mul(-1)
           for key in keys]
outcome = pd.concat(outcome, axis = 1, keys = keys)
outcome.add_suffix('_diff').reset_index()

   customer_id  count_sessions_diff  purchases_diff
0          203                   10              -1
1          484                    5              -3
2          582                   -9              -3
```

Comment: I am getting this error running when running 'temp': 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.

Comment: my error, made an edit now ... forgot to add the `expand=True` when splitting the columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to do it, using pandas subtract.  I am first setting the index as `customer_id`, so it isn't lost.  Then, every other column is subtracted by the column before it.

```
df.set_index("customer_id").iloc[:, 1::2].subtract(np.array(df.iloc[:, 1::2]), axis=1)
```

As you may notice, the `.iloc[]` is the same for both.  This is because I am setting the index for the first, which "drops" the first column (but this isn't applied to the second).

Using `np.array` inside the `subtract` means that it doesn't try to match column names.

Comment: I am getting the following error: ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (228, 29): given (228, 30)

Comment: Oh!  Try this: `
np.subtract(df.set_index("customer_id").iloc[:, 1::2],
            np.array(df.iloc[:, 1::2]), axis=1)`.  If this works instead, I will amend the answer.

Comment: Getting this error now: TypeError: subtract() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: Perhaps try without the `, axis=1` at the end.  It is strange that you are receiving all these errors!  With the mock data I am using, I haven't received one!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df,i = 'customer_id',j = 'quarter', stubnames = ['count_sessions','purchases'], suffix = '.*')
 .diff(periods = df.shape[0])
 .dropna()
 .rename('{}_diff'.format,axis=1))
```

Output:

```
                      count_sessions_diff  purchases_diff
customer_id quarter                                      
203         _q1_2022                 10.0            -1.0
484         _q1_2022                  5.0            -3.0
582         _q1_2022                 -9.0            -3.0
```